# Searching within my own database using typeahead.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, typeahead.js

I am very new to coding with Ruby/js and I need to be able to allow users to search for other users within the database. I have been trying to implement my own with AJAX but I have had no success. I found a link about typeahead.js and I think maybe this is what I need, but I don't know where to start. Please will you show me how to use typeahead.js to allow users to see suggestions before picking a user.

Here is what I've got so far:

-I have a view to allow users to create a meeting (the point of the search bar is that I need them to select who they want the meeting with):

events\new.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form">
      <h1>Create A Meeting</h1>

      <%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>

          <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Title" %>
          <!--< f.collection_select :location, Location.all, :id, :locName %> FOR WHEN LOCATIONS ARE A THING-->
          <%= f.text_field :description, :placeholder => "Short Description" %>

          <div>
            <h2>Who's involved?</h2>



          </div>


          <div>
            <h2>Check out a day and see who's free</h2>
            <%= f.select :day, Date::DAYNAMES.zip((0..6).to_a)  %>
          </div>



          <div>
            <h2>when do you want it to start?</h2>
            <%= f.datetime_select :starts_at, :placeholder => "when do you want it?"   %>
          </div>



          <div>
            <h2>when do you want it to end?</h2>
            <%= f.datetime_select :ends_at, :placeholder => "when should it end?"  %>
          </div>


          <%= f.submit "Create Meeting", class: "btn-submit" %>
      <% end %>

      <div class = "searchbar">
      <%= render partial: 'customers/_search', :object => @customers, locals:{} %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have rendered in a partial which will contain the search bar html to search for customers(users) (I don't know if this is necessary anymore)

here is this html customers\ _search.html.erb:

```
<input type="text" class="search" id="searchinput" placeholder="Who's involved?">
```

I don't think I can use bootstrap but I'd rather just get the functionality than the appearance right. I have been looking at this http://censore.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/twitter-typeheadjs-basic-example-with.html

but I don't know how to implement the scripts in ruby on rails. I have typeahead gem. I don't understand bloodhound or whether I need it.

All I want to be able to do is let someone search for customers within the database. In terms of the JS, I don't know which parts I need/don't need or need to change to work for my application.

I know this is quite an open question but I am literally tearing my hair out over this, please somebody help me. I don't want to fail

Thanks